# How to drag down formula in excel where the letter increments by 1 and the number is locked?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

The cell starts with this

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!B2:Z20,Sheet2!$C$2,1)
```

as I drag it down it, the last cell should show

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!Z2:AX20,Sheet2!$C$2,1)
```

Comment: So, it will shift 1 column to right.

Comment: Maybe something like: `=INDEX(INDEX(Sheet1!$2:$20,,ROW(A2)):INDEX(Sheet1!$2:$20,,ROW(A25)),Sheet2!C$2,1)` can work when you drag it down?

Comment: @JvdV Thanks! You got it!!!

If you could post it as a answer i can flag it as the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my previous comment, it looks like you can use:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(Sheet1!$2:$20,,ROW(A2)):INDEX(Sheet1!$2:$20,,ROW(A25)),Sheet2!C$2,1)
```

Drag down.